# Loading ActiveRecord models in the proper order outside of a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sti

How do I load/require my activerecord models in the proper order outside of a rails app.  I have many STI models and I am getting an uninitialized constant exception.

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../../../app/models", __FILE__)
require "active_record"

Dir["#{File.expand_path('../../../app/models', __FILE__)}/*.rb"].each do |path|
  require "#{File.basename(path, '.rb')}"
end
```

I have a lot of jobs that I need to run with resque and I would rather not have my rails app load everytime and be deployed to all of the worker machines

EDIT:  One point to clarify as well.  There are two projects a Rails project and a project that is a rails engine which contains my models.  I dont load the rails engine itself with my resque jobs I just use the snippet above in a separate class to load active record on the models.  This always worked until I added some STI models which because of the naming caused the children to attempt to be loaded before the parent. The rails engine project loads just fine in the rails project no issues there this is just because I am trying to use active record outside of a rails project.

Comment: Could you please post some code? What exactly did you try?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed my issue.  There may be a better way but this does it for me.

```
basedir = File.expand_path('../../../app/models', __FILE__) 
Dir["#{basedir}/*.rb"].each do |path|
  name = "#{File.basename(path, '.rb')}"
  autoload name.classify.to_sym, "#{basedir}/#{name}"
end
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution if you don't want to autoload is to require the base class in the children classes. Explicitly requiring dependencies is a good thing. :)

**app/models/profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**app/models/student.rb**

```
require 'models/profile'

class Student < Profile
end
```

**app/models/teacher.rb**

```
require 'models/profile'

class Teacher < Profile
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Models will be autoloaded on their first mention. So just name them somewhere in a proper order (say, in `config/initializers/load_order.rb`):

```
Product
LineItem
Cart
```

and check if it helps.

Comment: This is not inside a rails app so initializers dont do me much good.  The rails app itself starts up just fine and uses the models without issue.

Comment: What do you mean under "outside of Rails app"? You reuse you models somewhere else?

Comment: Yes.  See my clarification in my original post.